# How to share an array state between modules in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'am trying to build a simple game with Node and Socket.io. I keep an array of connected players.

On connection I add a player, on disconnect I remove it. Pretty simple. I had my all socket events in my main file and any socket event could access the array if needed.

The problem accrued when I wanted to remove my socket events from the file and put them in separate modules.

I thought I would simply pass the connectedPlayers to the module like that:

```
require('./app_modules/socket-messages.js')(io, db, _, connectedPlayers);
```

But it doesn't work, modules are cashed and it won't share the state of the array. If I understood it right.

I read not to use global variables.

How can I keep an array of connected players and share it's state between modules?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the connectedPlayers are, but if they really have to be globally persistent state available to many modules, then maybe they should just be in a global variable or as a property on a global module object.

Comment: connectedPlayers is simply the array of connected players that I want to share, I also need to share it state. Making it global might work, I just don't want to do it because people don't recommend it.

Comment: Global data should not be used when it is not needed, but if it is needed, there is no substitute.

Comment: sounds reasonable mate

Comment: since io,db,_ could be shared in the module, it's weird that connectedPlayers not. are u sure you're not doing anything wrong somewhere?

Comment: plus, node cache your code, not variables u use

Answer (score 1):

Node newbie here myself but perhaps I could help out.

You might want to take a look at `module.exports` over at node [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports).

You can choose what you want to export and it can be a function or just a variable, maybe in this case we'll say you want to return your connectedPlayers array only and it's in a file called `currentPlayers.js`.

in `currentPlayers.js` I would have the array be exported:

```
var connectPlayers = ["Ray", "Jason", "Kingtak", "Derek", "Tyler"];
//some code then somewhere appropriate
module.exports = connectedPlayers;
```

Then anywhere I needed the info I'd add

```
var ConnectedPlayers = require('./path/to/file/currentPlayers');
```

Comment: Hey! The problem is, that modules are cashed so I would not be able to update it when. At least this is what I think is happening :)